# Sepia Effect in IOS

Tags: android, ios, swift, image-processing

I am developing an application in Android which has to apply Sepia effect on the uploaded image. Application is already. I came across a function in swift code which is applying Sepia effect.

```
func applySepia() -> UIImage?  {
        filterValue = 1
        let image = self.processPixels(filterValue: filterValue)

        guard let cgimg = image?.cgImage else {
            print("imageView doesn't have an image!")
            return self
        }

        let value = -filterValue

        print("sliderValue = \(filterValue)")
        print("value = \(value)")

        let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!)

        let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

        if let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
            let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimgresult!)
            return image.applySharpness(filterValue:filterValue)
        }

        return self
    }
```

Above function is using "CISepiaTone" filter to implement Sepia tone. Here "kCIInputIntensityKey" is passed as -1 which I am unable to understand. As per the documentation, it's value ranges between 0 to 1 but how it is allowing a negative value.  Due to this intensity value, the generated image does look like this:

[image]

In my opinion, after applying Sepia it should look like:
[image]

I am able to achieve the second image in android (which is truly Sepia Tone) using https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ColorMartix/blob/master/src/com/sample/colormatrix/Main.java

However, I couldn't find any built-in method or class in android which can be used to implement  Sepia Tone with negative intensity just like the way it is applied in IOS swift. Here are my questions:

1. How IOS is allowing negative value for kCIInputIntensityKey despite
   the fact that it should be ranged between 0-1.
2. After negative intensity values, Generated images does not look like
   a Sepia Tone.
3. How can I achieve the same effect in Android?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you pass a value between 0 and 1 on iOS do you get a sepia output?  Why are you looking for code on Android that accepts -1 when -1 doesn't work on iOS?

Comment: iOS is accepting -1 and producing very different results than a usual Sepia Tone. My problem is that I have to generate the same effect for Android.

Comment: So you want the to produce the output that you get with -1 on iOS on Android?

Comment: Want to implement on Android. But at the same time I want to understand what effect iOS applying with -1 value.

Comment: To apply sepia and get the result you have in the second image you first need to convert it to black & white, you can never get that result with a color image. I am commenting as an amateur photographer and not as a programmer so don’t ask me how it’s done in code :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for the comment. I already got the second image in android. I want to achieve the first image as this has been given by adding negative intensity to the Sepia effect. I am not sure if this is allowed but this is how iOS is generating the image.

Comment: I think you need to read my comment again, first you need to convert the image to [black & white](https://www.google.se/search?q=black+and+white+photography&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) then you can apply the sepia effect.